# Dropwizard DropwizardAppRule test multipart file upload

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I'm currently trying to write an IT test by calling a resource that takes MultiPartFormData as input.

It work when the application starts "normaly" but doesn't when started with DropwizardAppRule helper.

Here is my code :

```
@Test
public void importProductAndOfferCsvShopInput() {
    // Given
    var shopId = "id";
    var multipartHeaders = headers;
    multipartHeaders.putSingle("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    var file = new File("src/test/resources/import/products&offers.csv");
    var fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

    // When
    var response = QORUS_APP.client().target(String.format("http://localhost:%d/ui/shop-inputs/csv/%s", 8082, shopId))
                            .queryParam("importContentType", "BOTH")
                            .request()
                            .headers(multipartHeaders)
                            .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

    // Then
    assertThat(response.getStatusInfo()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK);
}
```

QORUS_APP is intanciated like so :

```
public abstract class AbstractRestResourceTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> QORUS_APP = ResourceSuite.QORUS_APP;
    private static final String USER_API_KEY = "authenticatedUserApiKey";

    protected static MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers;

    public AbstractRestResourceTest() {
        headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
        headers.putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.putSingle("Accept", "*/*");
        headers.putSingle(NgTokenAuthFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + USER_API_KEY);
    }
}
```

I get the following error :

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.

Note that there is the required registering of multipart in Application bootstrap :

```
    private List<Resource> configureJersey(Configuration config, Environment environment) {
    // adds some required features
    environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

UPDATE:

Thanks @paul-samsotha for taking time to answer.

I did the following:

```
@Test
public void importProductAndOfferCsvShopInput() {
    // Given
    var shopId = "5b03ebe9c9aa0423b4a73dce";
    var multipartHeaders = headers;
    multipartHeaders.putSingle("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    var file = new File("src/test/resources/import/products&offers.csv");
    var fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file);
    var multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

    // When
    var response = QORUS_APP.client()
                            .target(String.format("http://localhost:%d/ui/shop-inputs/csv/%s", 8082, shopId))
                            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                            .queryParam("importContentType", "BOTH")
                            .request()
                            .headers(multipartHeaders)
                            .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

    // Then
    assertThat(response.getStatusInfo()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK);
}
```

Just like you suggest.

Comment: `.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)` The media type of this part should not be multpart. You don't even need the second argument because you already set the media type when you constructed the FileDataBodyPart

Comment: Ok, I just did that. Removed the MediaType of the body part.
Can you explain to me why it's shouldn't be multipart and also what it is instead ?

Thank you a lotfor your help.

Comment: multipart is the media type of the _entire_ entity. Its called multipart because there are multiple parts and each part is its own serparate entity with its own separate content-type. In this case, the content-type of the file is application/octet-stream, as you declared when you constructed the FileDataBodyPart.

Comment: Sorry, you did not set the media type when you constructed the FileDataBodyPart. But there are three different constructors, one allows you to pass the MediaType. The javadoc for the one you are using states: _"Constructs the body part with the provided name and file, it predicts the MediaType of the file provided. For the known media types client will not need to set the media type explicitly."_ So as you can see, it is just guessed. You _could_ add it with the call to `bodyPart()` as you attempted, but in this case, you would use somethng like application/csv

Comment: Ok, it's very clear to me now. Thanks so much for the explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring on the client side before it sends out the request. [See the docs on Forms](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/forms.html), it will show you that you need to register the `MultiPartFeature` on the client side also. You can register it either with the `Client` or the `WebTarget`. Dropwizard suggests you register it with the `WebTarget`, as shown in the example.

```
var response = QORUS_APP.client()
        .target(...)
        .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
        ...
```